# get single row data into multiple row by calculating cell data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
create table #tmp (Name varchar(10), Code varchar(10), Date datetime, Total int)
insert into #tmp
select 'abc','A-8','2016-10-12',45
```

Now I want split data based on Total.

For example, if I need to split data by 20 then result should look like

```
Name    Code    Date        Total
abc     A-8     2016-10-12  20
abc     A-8     2016-10-12  20
abc     A-8     2016-10-12  5
```

You can see upper code and you can see that i split my single row into 3 rows with all data are same except Total.

Total should be calculate differently and because of the result I have 3 rows. If total is 65 then there will be 4 rows with same data and only Total will be changed, like 20, 20, 20, 5 and remains will be same.

I don't want to use any loop for this like WHILE etc.

Comment: Thanks @Jarlh for correcting Source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have a table like dbo.Nums

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Nums

n
-----------
1
2
3
4
5
...
10000000
```

Or you can use below query for the same purpose.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) FROM sys.all_objects
```

Then the query would be

```
DECLARE @d AS INT = 20;

SELECT #tmp.Name, Code, Date, @d AS Total
FROM #tmp
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums
WHERE dbo.Nums.n <= (#tmp.Total / @d)
UNION ALL
SELECT #tmp.Name, Code, Date, (Total % @d) AS Total
FROM #tmp
WHERE (Total % @d) <> 0
```

Comment: Is it must to create a table like dbo.Nums?

Comment: Such a table make your sql life easier. You only need to generate it once. See how people try hard to [generate such data](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tally table for it. Tally table should have records as per your requirement say from 1 to 5 or 1 to 100. I have created tmp tally table but you can create actual tally table for it as shown below:

```
create table #tmp (Name varchar(10), Code varchar(10), Date datetime, Total int)
create table #tmp_tally (sno int)

insert into #tmp_tally
select 1
union all
select 2
union all
select 3
union all
select 4
union all
select 5

insert into #tmp
select 'abc','A-8','2016-10-12',45;

select #tmp.*, sno,case when ceiling(total/20) >= sno  then 20 else total % 20 end
from #tmp,#tmp_tally
where ceiling(total/20) >= sno- case when (total % 20) = 0 then 0 else 1 end
```